# Writeprocessmemory problem

Tags: c#

I want to add 00 00 00 00 00 00 ( a lot of empty spaces ) after the login address I set with WriteProcessMemory. So if login address is right now = login.blaha.com, I want to change it to blaha.net, but then theres characters after blaha.net that I don't need. How to fix this??

Comment: It's very hard to understand what your question is – could you elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases:

- If it its a nullterminated string, insert a null-terminating byte ('\0')
- If the string length is defined in the string itself just change the string length in memory.

The additional characters doesn't matter after these changes, because nobody will have access to them anymore.

Comment: @Marus: If it worked then you should give codymanix an upvote and accept his answer.